# CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifier() crashes program

Tags: java, io

I have some code that works in Windows 7 but when I try the same code on a Windows 10 machine the program closes down. Here's the code:

```
try {
    CommPortIdentifier portId = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifier((String)openParameters[0]);
    this._serCommPort = (SerialPort) portId.open("PTxCore", 1000);
    this._serCommPort.setSerialPortParams((int)openParameters[1], (int)openParameters[2], SerialPort.STOPBITS_1, (int)openParameters[3]);
    this._serCommPort.setFlowControlMode(SerialPort.FLOWCONTROL_NONE);
    this._serCommPort.addEventListener(this);
    this._serCommPort.notifyOnDataAvailable(true);
    this._commsOutStream = this._serCommPort.getOutputStream();
    this._commsInStream = this._serCommPort.getInputStream();

    this.clearBuffer();

    this.onTraceEvent(TraceEventArgs.Mode.Hidden, "{Open}");
}
catch (UnsupportedCommOperationException | TooManyListenersException | IOException | PortInUseException | NoSuchPortException ex) {
    throw new PTxCoreException(ex.getMessage(), ex.getClass().getName());
}
}
```

No exception is caught, it simply closes down. I tried different versions of Eclipse (32/64 bit) and looked everywhere on the web but can't find a solution. Any any idea why this might be happening? Serialio.jar (which I think handles this?) is compatible with Windows 10, apparently.

When it closes down I get this error:

...javaw.exe

Also there's this stuff at the bottom of Eclipse:

```
javax.comm.SerialPort implementation: version 3.8
Copyright (c) 1998-2009 Serialio.com, All Rights Reserved.
Serialio Library: version 10.1.2: build 9221
Copyright (c) 1996-2012 Serialio.com, All Rights Reserved.
os.name="Windows 10"  os.arch="x86"
osName=Windows 10 osArch=x86
Platform not supported, check VM properties os.name & os.arch
```

Comment: Um? Are you sure you're on the right thread alfasin? Where did that come from?

Comment: Any ideas on this problem? :/

Answer (score 0):

Its a bit of a late response but it might help someone. I was getting the same error. This was because I was using older version of Serialio.jar. After upgrading it to latest one (I think build: 9233 ?) it started running fine on Windows 10.